# Add a new button to existing web application

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need to add a new button that when clicked shows an open dialog to browse and select an Excel sheet, uploading and importing it.

Answer (score 3):

just use the html `input` tag,

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

as it comes with the browse button. that allows you to upload .

To upload a `excel` file  ,

For **Excel Files 2003-2007** (.xls), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
```

For **Excel Files 2010** (.xlsx), use:

```
<input type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
```

validates the whether its a excel file

Comment: and then use javascript for verifying if the input was excel sheet.

Comment: Can do it using html too :)